# how to appned the data when there is data for a weekday in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have response from the API like this:

```
     { 

      "week_days": [ "Wed", "Thu", "Sat" ],
      "data": [
                { "temp": 50, "pressure": 50, "humidity" : 20 },
                { "temp": 45, "pressure": 40, "humidity" : 10 },
                { "temp": 30, "pressure": 55, "humidity" : 10 }

              ]

      }
```

I want, If there is no data for a particular day in a week the "data" values should be zero.

Expected output:

```
           week_days = [ 'Sat', 'Fri', 'Thu', 'Wed', 'Tue', 'Mon', 'Sun' ]

           temp = [ 30, 0, 45, 50, 0, 0, 0 ]
           pressure = [ 55, 0, 40, 50, 0, 0, 0 ]
           humidity = [ 20, 0, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

Output Explanation:

If we see week_days list starts with current day and ends with tomorrow's day, I have done this by:

```
        week = []
        for day in range(0, 7):
            days = (datetime.today().date() - timedelta(days=day)).strftime('%a')
            week.append(days)
```

After that I have declared 3 empty lists:

```
             temp = []
             pressure = []
             humidity = []
```

after that, I don't no how to proceed can anyone help me.

Comment: How will you differentiate a temperature of 0 from missing data? 0 doesn't seem to be a good choice to represent it...

Comment: I have to display the data in graphical format If there is no data for day, it should be zero @ThierryLathuille